# My Work Items gone in TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs, tfs-workitem

We use VS2008 with TFS for source control at my workplace and it works fine, however today we experienced a problem when trying to associate our pending changes with a work item. 
Usually when I want to associate changes with a work item I just go to the second tab from the top in the "pending changes" window, check the work item that fits the changes and check in. Today however, all my work items were gone from the list. I can select a suitable query from the drop down box and this works fine, so the projects are there.

I think the problem might have something to do with the "My Work Items" query being associated with the wrong TFS project (there are two on our TFS-server) but I don't know how to fix this. The same problem occurred for most of my colleagues with some (possible) variations.

So... **how do I restore "My Work Items"** to the pending changes window?

EDIT: The problem still persists in a way but I worked my way around it by removing the second project in the Team Explorer. This is acceptable (for now) since that project is not currently active. I am not content with this being a good long term solution, however...

EDIT: I know that I may not have provided enough information for anyone to understand what really is the problem, still, I'll keep it up for now in case someone has had the same problem and knows how to fix it :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close all instances of visual studio and try this in the comandline: "devenv.exe /resetuserdata"

Comment: Doesn't that reset all my settings in vs? I have a bunch of font/window placement settings I'd rather keep...

Comment: yes but i guess solving your problem and keep on developing should be more important then a few settings.last time i lost things in tfs, this was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The first time I've seen with this is when I was associating a checkin with a work item and the queries had changed to another Team Project.  Can you check the queries are pulling from the correct team project?

Another thing to check is the Event Log of your TFS server for any oddities.

Comment: I think you are getting close to the problem here. I have 2 projects. I removed one for a quick fix. Still... "My work items" exist under "Team Querries" for Project1. On Project2 (current), however, it does not. Instead i have "My work Items for All Team Projects.wiq". I don't know how to fix that

Comment: Sounds like the query is amiss.  Can you create a custom query to see if the work items exist?

Comment: Yepp... the work items are definately there. All my colleagues have the standard "My Work Items" querry but mine looks a little different for some odd reason